# RSpec test broken by pagination (Kaminari)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, pagination, kaminari

I have a view spec that was passing but is broken now that pagination (via Kaminari gem) has been added to the view. I'm still trying to get my head around RSpec's syntax...so looking for help in getting this to pass as the page works fine in the browser. *I'm aware that many people frown on view specs for being brittle (probably for reasons like this) but I still would like to keep this one passing*

I am assigning some stubbed posts to the @posts array. But arrays don't respond to `current_page`. So how should I handle this in RSpec?

```
Failures:

  1) posts/index.html.haml renders a list of posts
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x000001028ab4e0>
     # ./app/views/posts/index.html.haml:31:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_haml__291454070937541541_2193463480'
     # ./spec/views/posts/index.html.haml_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

`spec/views/posts/index.html.haml_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "posts/index.html.haml" do
  before(:each) do
    ...
    assign(:posts, [
      Factory.stub(:post),
      Factory.stub(:post)
    ])    
    view.should_receive(:date_as_string).twice.and_return("June 17, 2011")
    ...
  end

  it "renders a list of posts" do
    render
    rendered.should have_content("June 17, 2011")
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I know you already accepted another answer, but I'm concerned that by doing the stubbing you did that you just stubbed out a bug in your code. The error above implies that you're calling @posts.current_page in your controller. I can see @ posts.first.current_page or controller.current_page being valid, but @ posts.current_page probably isn't.

Comment: good point! so, should I, perhaps be stubbing out the controller? I'm not entirely sure what Kaminari expects to call `current_page` on?!? I only know the spec *was* failing because the posts array doesn't respond to it...but, you're right, that does seem odd? *I'll leave this open for a bit to see if a better answer presents itself.*

Comment: Can you also post the relevant controller code ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can also do something like below:

```
assign(:posts, Kaminari.paginate_array([
        Factory.stub(:post),
        Factory.stub(:post)
      ]).page(1))
```

Comment: This method fits the Rails scaffolded code nicely. Just wrap the generated stub_model array with the Kaminari.paginate_array(...).page(1) and Viola! Working specs.

Comment: `Kaminari.paginate_array(...).page(1)` works in my case as well

Answer (score 17):

You should stub the behavior, try this:

```
before(:each) do
  ...
  posts = [Factory.stub(:post), Factory.stub(:post)]
  posts.stub!(:current_page).and_return(1)
  posts.stub!(:total_pages).and_return(2)
  assign(:posts, posts)    
  view.should_receive(:date_as_string).twice.and_return("June 17, 2011")
  ...
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!  For anyone else watching I also had to stub out two other methods `:num_pages` and `:limit_value` in the same fashion as `:current_value` is above...and the value I'm returning for each of them is an integer `(1)`.  Specs passing swimmingly...thanks!

Comment: With Rspec 3.1 doing **posts.stub!(:current_page).and_return(1)** thrown error **Undefined method stub! for Array**. However @manojlds answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8885026/936494 worked for me.

Comment: @Jignesh I guess you have to replace `stub!` with `stub`. Anyway, the other answer is better :)